# When compiling a finished project, a lot of the same type of errors

Tags: c#, compilation

I'm compiling a complete program that was developed many years ago. But there are numerous errors. Mostly related to brackets `<>`.

For example "CS1526:

> A new expression requires (), [] or {} after type

or:

> error CS1525: Unexpected symbol <

I can't figure out why this is happening. Maybe I need to connect something to the project or change the settings? I am not strong in C# but I need to compile this.

[1 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpYHQ.png)

[2 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU5GO.png)

Comment: This code is not vaild c#, it is compiler generated code that uses type and member names that are invalid for user code.

Comment: can I somehow build a project with this code?

Comment: If you used a decompiler for that then you should set it to decompile compiler-generated code such as lambdas and `yield`

Comment: @Charlieface No, I download project with this code and i don't know how I can decompile it